# Referencing with WCF Webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have used web-services before and understand the concept. However now I have set up a WCF Webservice, but I have a question about the use of it. (In how the tutorial is set up.)

I have the following things set up:

- WCF Service Library (Called CalculatorService)
- Service Host (Called CalculatorServiceHost)
- Service Proxy (Called CalculatorServiceProxy, is using ClientBase)
- Service Client (Called CalculatorServiceClient)

---

How I understand it is as follows;

1. The Service Library contains the service/object that can be used in the webservice. Lets say it is a calculator with the method addition.
2. The Host makes this class with its functions available to the client side.
3. The proxy sends and receives the message from the client to the configured endpoint.
4. The client can call functions from the service through the proxy.

The tutorial sets up the proxy as follows:

```
public class MyCalculatorServiceProxy : ClientBase<ICalculator>, ICalculator {
    public int Add(int num1, int num2){
        return base.Channel.Add(num1, num2);
    }
}
```

This means that in the Proxy I have to reference at least to the assembly which contains the ICalculator. The Client also complains of having no reference to the interface if it is missing a reference to the same assembly.

In this tutorial the interface and the class/service, that inherits the interface, are in the same assembly. Thus referencing the assembly for the interface on the client side means that you are also able to create an instance of the 'Calculator' class and don't even need the WCF Service to call the functions.

Does this mean that you always need two assemblies with WCF Services. One with the interfaces and one with the classes/services?

Correct me if I am wrong or if someone has some additional information/comments.

Comment: Yes, basically you should always separate contracts and operational things. Contracts being the interface, requests and responses

Comment: No, you can have the service contract and the service implementation in the same assembly.  Sometimes it's useful to separate them - for example, at work we have the service contracts (the interfaces) in a separate assembly.  This allows the clients to reference the assembly and use `ChannelFactory<T>` to generate the proxies for the client.  But it's perfectly legitimate to have them both in one assembly.

Comment: You do not need to reference the calculator assembly, you can use the wsdl to generate the proxy. Or if the wcf service exposes the metadata you can add the web reference and it will create the proxy. But I would recommend on separating the contracts and poco classes to their own assembly to be referenced in both the client and the server.

Comment: @Tim but what I am wondering is, if you reference an assembly with the service contracts and implementation. Why use the services over a webservice through a proxy. If you can call the functions right away through the reference of the other assembly?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I looked into it and created the proxy indeed through the service reference (WSDL), and not through the assembly reference. That works, had to set the policyversion on metadata though! Thanx, this was what I was looking for. (Can u rephrase your comment as an answer, so I can accept it!)

Answer (score 0):

> @Tim but what I am wondering is, if you reference an assembly with the
>   service contracts and implementation. Why use the services over a
>   webservice through a proxy. If you can call the functions right away
>   through the reference of the other assembly?

If you do that then instead of having one service that communicates with your database (for example) you've got every possible client of that service talking to your database instead. You'll have connection strings everywhere. If you need to modify the service code, you'll have to deploy the updates to more applications. You lose security, scalability, and maintainability.

But that's great for writing unit and integration tests.

Comment: That's not what my comment is about. My comment is about having private code, and not wanting to share it with the client. This can be done through a webservice. But my question is why would you do that if you have to reference it and can call it straight away. However JanneMatikainen gave the good answer/suggestion.